# Error message when adding windows login to Dynamics NAV 2009 classic with sql server

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I have a user that is created on the windows domain, and added to the Administrators group on my server. The user can log in to the machine,

However, when I open Tools->Security->Windows Logins and try to add the user, I get the following message:
"You do not have the required SQL Server permissions to perform the current security activity".

What can I do to get the Windows User set up in NAV?

I am running Nav 2009 R2 wiht SQL server on a windows 2008 server, using the Cronus test database.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - I had to run Dynamics Nav as administrator, in order to add the user.